# Controllers и factory

Tags: php, javascript, angularjs

Возможно ли подключить в один контроллер две разные factory?

Comment: вы какую версию angularjs используете?

Answer (score 1):

Да возможно. Вы можете инжектить различные factory для вашего контроллера.

Вот [пример](https://plnkr.co/edit/A5LQRQ6t3DuIz4zDjXu4?p=preview) написаный на angular 1:

```
app.factory('factory1', function(){
  return {
    text: 'text from factory1'
  }
})

app.factory('factory2', function(){
  return {
    text: 'text from factory2'
  }
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, factory1, factory2) {
  $scope.factory1 = factory1;
  $scope.factory2 = factory2;
});
```